# FAL resource not accessible in fluid template - where to look?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, fal

In a custom extbase extension, we have an image field set up like this:

Model

```
/**
 * Returns the picture
 *
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $picture
 */
public function getPicture()
{
    return $this->picture;
}

/**
 * Sets the picture
 *
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $picture
 * @return void
 */
public function setPicture(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $picture)
{
    $this->picture = $picture;
}
```

TCA

```
    'picture' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_address.picture',
        'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
            'picture',
            array(
                'appearance' => array(
                    'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
                ),
                'foreign_types' => array(
                    '0' => array(
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ),
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => array(
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ),
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => array(
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ),
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => array(
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ),
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => array(
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ),
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => array(
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    )
                ),
                'maxitems' => 1
            ),
            $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
        ),
    ),
```

When I try to access the FAL resource in fluid via

```
<f:image src="{myextitem.picture}" width="600" height="750c"/>
```

an empty image tag is output.

I can access the original resource with

```
<f:image src="{myextitem.picture.originalResource.publicUrl}" width="600" height="750c"/>
```

but that doesn't respect modifications to the image by the crop wizard.

Where shoud I look to make the FAL resource accessible by fluid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look in the ImageViewHelpers `render()` method. The accepted parameter are explained there:

```
* @param string $src a path to a file, a combined FAL identifier or an uid (int). If $treatIdAsReference is set, the integer is considered the uid of the sys_file_reference record. If you already got a FAL object, consider using the $image parameter instead
* ...
* @param FileInterface|AbstractFileFolder $image a FAL object
```

So if you use `src="{imageResource}"` it won't work because `src` expects a string.

Try `<f:image image="{imageResource}" width="600" height="750c"/>` instead.

Comment: yeaaaaah thanks!! I wasn't conscious of the two different params. It's a good hint to look in the source for the VH. Is there an IDE that also gathers information about viewhelpers? I'm using atom/sublime, and so I don't think about looking in the core as often as I probably should.